# Unmarshall XML String using Java

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

Hi I am writing a unmarshalling script for an XML response string using java. I have mentioned the xml response, unmarshalling code and the error i received.
Please help in fixing the issue and also advise me on the problem.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new     StringReader(response.toString() ) ) );
System.out.println(customer.getNAME());


Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"response"). Expected elements are <{}customer>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <control>
        <status>success</status>
        <senderid>XXXX</senderid>
        <controlid>ControlIdHere</controlid>
        <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
        <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
  </control>
  <operation>
        <authentication>
              <status>XXXX</status>
              <userid>XXXX</userid>
              <companyid>XXXXXX</companyid>
              <sessiontimestamp>2014-08-12T03:49:00-07:00</sessiontimestamp>
        </authentication>
        <result>
              <status>success</status>
              <function>readByQuery</function>
              <controlid>testControlId</controlid>
              <data listtype="customer" count="26" totalcount="26" numremaining="0">
                    <customer>
                          <RECORDNO>15</RECORDNO>
                          <CUSTOMERID>RIC001</CUSTOMERID>
                          <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
                          <ENTITY>CRIC001</ENTITY>
                          <PARENTKEY></PARENTKEY>
                          <PARENTID></PARENTID>
                          <PARENTNAME></PARENTNAME>
                       </customer>
            <customer>
                          <RECORDNO>15</RECORDNO>
                          <CUSTOMERID>RIC001</CUSTOMERID>
                          <NAME>BBB</NAME>
                          <ENTITY>CRIC001</ENTITY>
                          <PARENTKEY></PARENTKEY>
                          <PARENTID></PARENTID>
                          <PARENTNAME></PARENTNAME>
                       </customer>
                                      </data>
        </result>
  </operation>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling the unmarshaller that you want a `Customer` object and will give a XML string representing a `Customer`, but you are passing it a XML string that represents a `Response` object. If you have a `Response` class, use it to create the `JAXBContext` instance. If not, get the string representing the `Customer` object in the response

```
<customer>
      <name>ABC</name>
      <country>India<country>
</customer>
```

and use with the unmarshaller.

== **Update** ==
Assuming you do not have a `Response` or a `Data` class, you can use code similar to the following;

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new StringReader(response.toString()));
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
    // Advance to the "Customer" elements
    while (xsr.hasNext()) {
        if (xsr.isStartElement() && "customer".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
            // Unmarshal to Customer
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Customer.class).getValue();
            customers.add();
        }
        xsr.next();
     }
```

Comment: For which part? Do you have a `Response` class?

Comment: Priyesh. Thanks for the solution I got it. Priyesh I do have Data and  customer class.I have read in forums that looping can be avoided by setting up a XML root name annotation. Can you please look into this and suggest me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284258/jaxb-unmarshalling-xml-string-looping-through-all-tags

Answer (score 2):

You're currently trying to turn the XML, which is opened with a `<response>` tag, into the Customer object.

You need to provide the  element specifically to the JAXBUnmarshaller for this to work.  For example:

```
<customer>
      <name>ABC</name>
      <country>India<country>
</customer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML string is not valid XML (closing tag missing), but I assume that is a mistake when posting the question?

It looks like JAXB isn't expecting the `<response>` root element when unmarshalling to a Customer object. What does the Customer class look like?

Answer (score 1):

See this question how to walk through the XML until you reached the customer element. From there you can unmarshall the XML :

[How to get a particular element through JAXB xml parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358769/how-to-get-a-particular-element-through-jaxb-xml-parsing)

Comment: Thanks for the share. I am new to programming. I think this will work.I will try and get back to you.

Answer (score -2):

Java Class must be decalared with

@XMLRootElement
class Response